# Finding Limit of Sequence (x^x)/ (x!)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the summation of (x^x) / (x!) from 1 to infinity. Is it possible to prove the divergence of this series using an nth term test. Someone in my class tried to show that x! can be rewritten as (x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)... and eventually the variable term of x^x will be equal to the numerator as x approaches infinity. Thus, he/she concluded that the limit is 1 and the series diverges.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the final answer (that is, use the check mark button) to award the poster with the best given answer to you. Some new people tend to forget this.

Comment: As an aside, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} \quad = \quad \int_0^\infty \frac{E(x)}{e^x} dx$$ where $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to 0} n^n = 1,$ and $$E(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n} \qquad \text{and} \qquad e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 2):

You could observe that $\dfrac{n^n}{n!} \ge n$ and use the simple comparison test.

Comment: Is that obvious? that its greater? but im wondering if theres a way using nth term.

Comment: @JohnKim Yes, it should be obvious that $\frac{n^n}{n!}\geq n$ for all $n\geq 1$ since $\frac{n}{n-k}\geq \frac{n}{n}=1$ for any positive $k$, you have $\frac{n^n}{n!} = \frac{n}{1}\frac{n}{2}\frac{n}{3}\cdots\frac{n}{(n-1)}\frac{n}{n}\geq \frac{n}{1}\frac{n}{n}\frac{n}{n}\cdots\frac{n}{n} = n$

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want the limit of the sequence or of the series (aka summation).  It's obvious that $n^n>n!$ so $\frac{n^n}{n!}>1$.  Since a series converges only if the terms go to zero, this shows the summation diverges.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Oops, how embarrassing!